# CSS grid building animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I would like to build a background animation when a website is opened. I want to create a grid on the whole website, but I also want it to build gradually. Does any body have an idea how I could build this grid gradually?

This is something I wrote for an animation of a single line:

```
div{
  height:0px;
  width:1px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  
  -webkit-animation: increase 3s;
  -moz-animation:    increase 3s; 
  -o-animation:      increase 3s; 
  animation:         increase 3s; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes increase {
    100% {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

The problem is I want to do this animation in the background, how can I achieve this?

Another option is to use a rectangle that repeats itself in the background. Is there a way to animate this?(rectangles appearing gradually)
Background image:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: why is this tagged with css-animations, where is the animation in this? Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: As I stated in the question, I need the grid to appear gradually. My guess is this can be done through some kind of animation.

Answer (score 1):

Without sample code, can't do much. Here is a CSS approach to do a Grid-like reveal. You could crop your image in squares and use as separate `background` for each of the boxes, or use one image and set the `background-position` of each box.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.block {
  border: solid 1px #252525;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: reveal 1s forwards ease;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.block:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 50ms;
}

.block:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 100ms;
}

.block:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 150ms;
}

.block:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 200ms;
}

.block:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 250ms;
}

.block:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}

.block:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 350ms;
}

.block:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}

.block:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: 450ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I the block stay after the animation and how to set the width of this grid 100% of the backround.

Comment: @LaForge1071 check my updated code. You essentially remove `max-width` from `.grid` and you set the animation to `forwards` instead of `infinite`. I set the height to `100vh`, however I believe this won't work responsively for an image. We need a sample code or example to help you more.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make just one block that repeats itself instead of putting multiple in the html.I don't have any sample code because this was just an idea.

Comment: @LaForge1071 apart from inserting blocks with JavaScript, if you want the animation to be adjustable for each block (meaning 'revealing' one by one horizontally or vertically) then you have to have separate block elements. Otherwise, if you want to reveal alltogether in a specific direction, you can do CSS things like positioning the entire structure out of the window and then applying a transition to get it back to the default position.